# Aspectj aspect for specifying multiple packages

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I wanted to specify a pattern for aspectj @Around aspect that includes multiple packages.

```
Example : package 1 : aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
          package 2 : aaa.bbb.ccc.eee 
          package 3 : aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.fff
```

Pattern which i used :

```
@Around("execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.*.*(..)) && execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.eee..*.*(..))")
    i.e Intercept packages aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd, aaa.bbb.ccc.eee and any sub-package of aaa.bbb.ccc.eee
```

But this pattern doesnt seem to work. Though specifying a single pattern without && condition works.

Can someone suggest whats wrong with this pattern?

Thanks,
Gayathri

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`&&` stands for logical `AND`. What You need here is a logical `OR`, that in AspectJ is `||`.

```
@Pointcut("execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.*.*(..))")
public void methodInDddPackage() {}

@Pointcut("execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.*.*(..))")
public void methodInEeePackage() {}

@Pointcut("methodInDddPackage() || methodInEeePackage()")
public void methodInDddOrEeePackage() {}
```

Below equivalent inline expression:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd.*.*(..)) || execution(* aaa.bbb.ccc.eee.*.*(..))")
public void methodInDddOrEeePackageInline() {}
```

See this [Spring AOP documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-combining) page for more details.