# Applying Aspects on package and supackages

Tags: aspectj, aspects

I am using AspectJ to apply aspects on methods of classes under packages org.apache.http, org.apache.http.entity, org.apache.http.impl, org.apache.http.io and similarly others.

I used the aspects as below but it is not applied.

```
public pointcut capturehttp():within(org.apache.http..*) && (call(public * *(..)) || call(private * *(..)));
after():capturehttp()
{

    System.out.println("In test test test testy test http method set");

}
```

I also tried as suggested in [Aspectj aspect for specifying multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819300/aspectj-aspect-for-specifying-multiple-packages) but it didn't work.
Please suggest to me where I am wrong?

Comment: Please specify what are you trying to achieve by editing your question. Your pointcut selects all method call join points to public or private methods **where the executing code is defined in package `org.apache.http`**.

Comment: There are different sub packages under org.apache.http and I want to apply aspects in all methods of these packages. Please help me out.

Comment: By asking what are you trying to achieve I'm expecting an answer along the lines *"I want to capture all method calls from my code in package `com.my.package` to code in `org.apache.http`"*. What your example is about is *"capture calls from `org.apache.http` to any public or private method under any package"*. I suspect this is not what you want, so please specify exactly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: My program is using the HttpCore 4.4.5(https://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) that has package org.apache.http, org.apache.http.entity, org.apache.http.impl and others. I want to intercept all calls made from my program to methods of these packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following aspect:

```aspectj
public aspect HttpCoreAspect {

    pointcut captureHttp(): within(com.my.pckg..*) && !within(HttpCoreAspect) 
        && (call(* org.apache.http..*.*(..)) || call(org.apache.http..*.new(..)));

    after(): captureHttp() {
        System.out.println("Apache HttpCore was invoked");
    }

}
```

The `captureHttp()` pointcut above will capture method or constructor calls to any type in package `org.apache.http` or any subpackage, called from any code within package `com.my.pckg` or any of its subpackages, excluding calls made from the aspect `HttpCodeAspect` itself (should you happen to invoke HttpCore from your `after()` advice, we don't want an infinite recursion to happen).

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Would you mind accepting and upvoting my answer if it solved your problem?